# How to get my search bar working so it can call more than one variable

Tags: javascript, json, searchbar

Right now I have a search bar on my website and its only function is to call the categories within my list.

[picture of my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh8pM.png)

But my filter search on the right is already doing that. So, I was wondering if anybody could help me figure out how to program the search bar to search for the products instead, so that anybody who arrives to my list can get their results from these.

[products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh8pM.png)

Below is the code that I have, and again, its for only allowing my search bar to search category.

```js
   

var array_html = "";
    var data_array = boroughs[property];
    for (var i in data_array) {
      array_html +=
        "<b>" + "<u>"+
        data_array[i]["business"] +
        "</b></u><br />" + "<i>" +
        data_array[i]['adderess'] +
        "</i>"+
        data_array[i]['owner']   +
        "<br />"+
         '<a href="http://'+
        data_array[i]['website'] + '" target=_blank" title="Opens in a new window">' + 
        data_array[i]['website']+ '</a>'+
             data_array[i]['neighbourhood'] +
              "<br />"+
               '<a href="'+
              data_array[i]['maps']+ '" target=_blank" title="Opens in a new window">' + 
              '<p> Open Maps </p>' +'</a>'+ "<p class='products'>"+ //products is defined
data_array[i]["products"]+ '</p>' +
        "<br />"+   "<br />";
    }

    var collapse_html =
      '<div class="collapse show" id="' +
      property.split(" ").join("_") +
      '">' +
      '<div class="card card-body">' +
      array_html +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>";
    final_html += boroughs_html + collapse_html;
  }
  return final_html;
}
//search functionality


    const search_btn_input = document.getElementsByClassName(
      "search_btn_input "
    )[0];
    const categories = document.getElementsByClassName("category_name");
    const products = document.getElementsByClassName("products");

    search_btn_input.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
      var search_key = search_btn_input.value.toUpperCase(); 


      for (var i in categories) {
        var category_name = categories[i].innerHTML;
        var products_name = products[i].innerHTML;
        if (category_name != undefined) {
          category_name = category_name.toUpperCase();
        } else {
          return;
        }



    //search button recognizing the word
        if (category_name.includes(search_key)) {
          categories[
            i
          ].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.order = -1;
        } else {
          categories[
            i
          ].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.order = 0;
        }
      }
    });
```

ideally, when somebody inputs a product value in the search bar, it would just pull that one business with that product to the very top of the column.

Comment: How is this question related to Google Sheets?

Comment: all of the information on each business is being pulled from google sheets, and the search bar is calling the information by category, I just want to know how to make it call by the products instead. This isn't a question about google sheets though, I was just adding that in in case it mattered.